# Is "しょっと" an informal version of "ちょっと" in "よい……しょっと?"

Tags: meaning, nuances

Context: A child is preparing his props for a play. My first guess was that this was a variant of ちょっと, but I tried double checking on Google and got really weird grammar details that don't match the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Converted from an earlier comment on encouragement from @[naruto](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5010/). )*

I suspect that this is just a variant of the よいしょ call, basically kinda like "heave, ho!" in English, something said where the よい part is the windup, getting ready for a strong effort, and then the しょ part is where the person applies pressure / throws something / pulls hard / etc. If you can read Japanese, [here is the よいしょ page at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E3%81%97%E3%82%87-652619).